# How can I ensure my Javascript Lightbox is layered on top of other content?

Tags: html, css

Creating my first site and I'm getting this issue with lightbox? I've linked all the CSS, JS files etc. But for some reason it's appearing like below? Any clues?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

simply add

```
z-index: 9999;
```

to the CSS of the lightbox.

Make sure it is positioned, and it should render on top. although i have seen some lightboxes having problems layering on top of flash before.

Answer (score 0):

Without your source I can just guess, but since you seem to have a lot of layers on your page already, it looks like the lightbox is not coming up on top.

You should check the css for your lightbox, and if not present, add a z-index CSS property to it. Set it to a high number to make sure it ends up in front of everything else.